# Pandas "diff()" with string

Tags: python, pandas

How can I flag a row in a dataframe every time a column change its string value?

Ex:

Input

```
ColumnA   ColumnB
1            Blue
2            Blue
3            Red
4            Red
5            Yellow


#  diff won't work here with strings....  only works in numerical values
dataframe['changed'] = dataframe['ColumnB'].diff()        


ColumnA   ColumnB      changed
1            Blue         0
2            Blue         0
3            Red          1
4            Red          0
5            Yellow       1
```

Comment: Performance note: It might be better to simply use `np.bool` type instead of integers. `np.bool` takes up a single byte. I suppose you could use `np.int8` but by default `np.int64` or `np.int64` (whatever a C long is on your system) is used, I believe...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I get better performance with `ne` instead of using the actual `!=` comparison:

```
df['changed'] = df['ColumnB'].ne(df['ColumnB'].shift().bfill()).astype(int)
```

**Timings**

Using the following setup to produce a larger dataframe:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10**5, ignore_index=True)
```

I get the following timings:

```
%timeit df['ColumnB'].ne(df['ColumnB'].shift().bfill()).astype(int)
10 loops, best of 3: 38.1 ms per loop

%timeit (df.ColumnB != df.ColumnB.shift()).astype(int)
10 loops, best of 3: 77.7 ms per loop

%timeit df['ColumnB'] == df['ColumnB'].shift(1).fillna(df['ColumnB'])
10 loops, best of 3: 99.6 ms per loop

%timeit (df.ColumnB.ne(df.ColumnB.shift())).astype(int)
10 loops, best of 3: 19.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: Please can you add timings for `(df.ColumnB.ne(df.ColumnB.shift())).astype(int)` ?

Comment: @jezrael: Added the timing.  Using `ix` to make the first row 0 adds ~1 ms to the timing, so it looks to be fastest that way.

Comment: Hi, i am using this answer in my script but it returned me 'SettingWithCopyWarning', do you guys see that?
dff['changed'] = dff.col1.ne(dff.col1.shift(1))

Comment: @root How do i get the shift of the state count? that is `Blue -> Red` , `Red -> Yellow` in the same sequence as the were detected

Comment: @root Can i directly know the change in state from `Blue` to `Yellow` in spite of having `Red` in the middle?

Answer (score 10):

Use [`.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) and compare:

```
dataframe['changed'] = dataframe['ColumnB'] == dataframe['ColumnB'].shift(1).fillna(dataframe['ColumnB'])
```

Comment: very clean answer

Answer (score 7):

For me works compare with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html), then `NaN` was replaced `0` because before no value:

```
df['diff'] = (df.ColumnB != df.ColumnB.shift()).astype(int)
df.ix[0,'diff'] = 0
print (df)
   ColumnA ColumnB  diff
0        1    Blue     0
1        2    Blue     0
2        3     Red     1
3        4     Red     0
4        5  Yellow     1
```

Edit by [timings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40348884/2901002) of another answer - fastest is use `ne`:

```
df['diff'] = (df.ColumnB.ne(df.ColumnB.shift())).astype(int)
df.ix[0,'diff'] = 0
```

Comment: I wonder, is there a performance difference between this approach and simply using `!=`?

Comment: @jezrael That how to do the same thing based on two columns?

Comment: @Navroop - do you think `df[['ColumnA','ColumnB']].ne(df[['ColumnA','ColumnB']].shift()).any(axis=1).astype(int)` ?